# Converting old data to MySQL - how to make a select that merges these date, startdate and enddate fields?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on importing some old data so I've imported the csv files as VARCHAR fields as individually sorting out all the tables into proper column types is not feasable.

I need to extract the start and end date from the data, looks like the (very) old system used a date/time format for the date and a date/time format with a default date for the start and end time. I'd like to select and convert it to two fields eg starts_at and ends_at.

This is the old data format. All columns are VARCHAR.

```
id, appointmentdate, starttime endtime
1, 21/1/2016 00:00:00, 30/12/1899 09:00:00, 30/12/1899 17:00:00
```

I have this at the moment which gets me the date, if I could do it in this select that would be nice, but I'm not opposed to having to run an update after. Note I'm storing the original id for reference as og_id and Keeping my options open for what to do in null instances hence the IFNULL func.

```sql
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`my_table`
SELECT
    NULL, -- id
    IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE(IF(`a`.`appointmentdate` = '', NULL, `a`.`appointmentdate`),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'), NULL), -- starts_at
    IFNULL(STR_TO_DATE(IF(`a`.`appointmentdate` = '', NULL, `a`.`appointmentdate`),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'), NULL), -- ends_at
    `a`.`id` -- og_id
FROM
`old_db`.`old_table` `a`;
```

I would like the resulting row in the new table (which is properly typed INT, DATETIME, DATETIME, INT to be as follows.

```
id, starts_at, ends_at, og_id
1, 2016-01-21 09:00:00, 2016-01-21 17:00:00, 1
```

Comment: I am not clear what the question is - you have already converted appointment date so why can't you apply the same logic to starttime and endtime and simply apply a date function to extract the date portion. Please add expected outcome to clarify.

Comment: Yes, its a direct import of a csv to MySql as VARCHAR, so there's no column typing on it.

Comment: Updated the question a little to be clearer on what I'm trying to achieve based on the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Use substring_index and concat to get the opening an closing times for example

```
select str_to_date(concat(substring_index(`a`.`appointmentdate`,' ',1),'09:00:00'),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'),
       str_to_date(concat(substring_index(`a`.`appointmentdate`,' ',1),'17:00:00'),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S')
from `old_db`.`old_table` `a`;
```

or if you want to pick the times from the defaults

```
select 
       str_to_date(concat(substring_index(`a`.`appointmentdate`,' ',1),time(str_to_date(starttime,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'))),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S') startdt,
       str_to_date(concat(substring_index(`a`.`appointmentdate`,' ',1),time(str_to_date(endtime,'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'))),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S') enddt
from `old_db`.`old_table` `a`;
```

Comment: Ahh that looks promising, I'll just need to select the time part from the old columns I think.

Comment: Edited to pick times from defaults

Comment: Yep you put me on the right path, I just did it, similarly, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO new_data (id, appointmentdate, starttime, endtime)
SELECT id,
       STR_TO_DATE(appointmentdate, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'),
       STR_TO_DATE(starttime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'),
       STR_TO_DATE(endtime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S')
FROM old_data;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=348dc3732d889baba3e702276cf7be45)

If some data can be empty string which must be treated as NULL you may use

```sql
INSERT INTO new_data (id, appointmentdate, starttime, endtime)
SELECT id,
       STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(appointmentdate, ''), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'),
       STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(starttime, ''), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'),
       STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(endtime, ''), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S')
FROM old_data;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=24c4b22bfff75f1d6f27eff8bbab4f0a)

---

> please see the updated question

```sql
INSERT INTO new_data (id, appointmentdate, starttime, endtime, old_id)
SELECT NULL,
       STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(appointmentdate, ''), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'),
       STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(starttime, ''), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'),
       STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(endtime, ''), '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'),
       id
FROM old_data;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ce84ae1d6a591f58eeeae95df494dd10)

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I was trying to do, please see the updated question.

Comment: Sorry you've misunderstood the question.

Comment: @louisl Remove `endtime` from destination table structure and according expression from the query - and you will obtain strictly the output which you show from the source data provided. Or edit my fiddle, add YOUR source structure and data (you may use a link in your question) and show desired result for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using the concept from @P.Salmon I have done it with this.

```sql
INSERT INTO `my_db`.`my_table`
SELECT
    NULL, -- id
    CONCAT_WS(' ', DATE(STR_TO_DATE(IF(`a`.`appointmentdate` = '', NULL, `a`.`appointmentdate`),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S')), TIME(STR_TO_DATE(IF(`a`.`starttime` = '', NULL, `a`.`starttime`),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'))) as starts_at, -- starts_at
    CONCAT_WS(' ', DATE(STR_TO_DATE(IF(`a`.`appointmentdate` = '', NULL, `a`.`appointmentdate`),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S')), TIME(STR_TO_DATE(IF(`a`.`endtime` = '', NULL, `a`.`endtime`),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S'))) as ends_at -- ends_at
    `a`.`id` -- og_id
FROM
`old_db`.`old_table` `a`;
```